# Error while Creating Videos from images using ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I am trying to create videos from images sequence. I tried all the below code given in $ff_command variable.

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__);
$ff_command = "ffmpeg -f image2 -i {$path}/img%03d.jpg video.mpg";

$ff_command = "ffmpeg -r 10 -b 1800 -i {$path}/img%03d.jpg test1800.mpg";

$ff_command = "ffmpeg -i {$path}/img%03d.jpg -s 1280x720 -aspect 16:9 -r 24 -vb 20M teste.mp4";

$ff_command = "ffmpeg -f image2 -i {$path}/img%03d.jpg -vcodec mpeg4 -b 800k video.avi";

$ff_command = "ffmpeg -f image2 -i {$path}/img%03d.jpg -vcodec libx264 -b 800k video.avi";
```

Most of these commands are creating a video file. But when I open that video nothing comes or first image is coming for a split second and nothing after that

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here

I noticed that video is too short to see. Is it possible to increase the video duration so that we can see all the images?

Comment: do you get any error messages? if yes, please edit your post and add them to it.

Comment: @ben No. I did not get any error messages. As I mentioned in the post video was created but was unable to play

Comment: try to run the commands from terminal to see whats wrong there